# Save date startdate between end date laravel/php only with the days of the week marked

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

First of all, good morning.

The query may be a bit confusing but I will try to explain myself as best I can.

In this example I receive from a form a **start and end date**, along with an array with the days of the week between these two dates that I want to save recursively.

In the following request I have put a month of difference saving Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Friday(5), and and I don't know how from this to obtain the exact date of each of these days Y/m/d and save them.

My request:

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "OxIKlatx6q4BcFVfLc8aB0mxQzDmOEw627s9TaSq"
  "name" => "Dates to save"
  "start_date" => "07/06/2021"
  "end_date" => "08/07/2021"
  "days" => array:4 [▼ <- Thats my array of days from form being 0 sunday, 1 monday...
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
    2 => "5"
  ]
```

And my controller:

```
    $startDate=$request->start_date;
    $endDate=$request->end_date;

    $period = CarbonPeriod::create($startDate, $endDate);

    foreach ($period as $date) {
        // filter by day of week
        $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Format in your post is confusing, you have d/m/Y as input, mention wanting Y/m/d as output but use Y-m-d in the format. Anyway, if input is not ISO, you need `Carbon::createFromFormat()` to create the proper date for the period.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$period = CarbonPeriod::create(
    Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '07/06/2021'),
    Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '08/07/2021'),
)->filter(
    fn ($date) => in_array($date->dayOfWeek, [1, 4, 5]),
);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

For old versions of PHP:

```php
$days = [1, 4, 5];
$period = CarbonPeriod::create(
    Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '07/06/2021'),
    Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '08/07/2021')
)->filter(function ($date) use ($days) {
    return in_array($date->dayOfWeek, $days);
});
```

Comment: What's mean "fn"? And thats answer helps me, thanks KyleK

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the week number, it's hard to assume which *"Monday"* between `07/06/2021` and `08/06/2021` is being referred to.

I would recommend choosing a frontend library or implementation that sends actual dates to the server.

For example, [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/).

With this library, you can define multiple dates/ranges and have the assurance that your server would receive actual dates. i.e:

###### HTML

```html
            <article>
                <form action="">
                    <input name="attendance_dates" type="text" placeholder="Select Dates.." class="date-multiple" id="attendance-dates">
                    <input type="submit" id="date-multiple-submit-btn">
                </form>
            </article>
```

###### CSS

```css
article {
  padding: 16px;
  width: 50%
}
```

###### JS

```javascript
const fp = flatpickr(".date-multiple", {
    mode: "multiple",
    dateFormat: "Y-m-d"
});

    $("#date-multiple-submit-btn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your-form-submit-route",
            data: {
                "_method": "POST",
                "_token": $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr("content"),
                "name": "Dates to save",
                "dates": $("#attendance-dates").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
        });

    })
```

###### Controller

```php
$dates = empty($d = $request->attendance_dates) ? [] : explode($d); // [2021-06-14, 2021-06-23, 2021-06-12, 2021-07-14]
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/theAccountant/xmznjk9f/11/)